# At what temperature should I simmer bolognese to avoid burning?

Tags: temperature, reduction, simmer

Bolognese requires a long period of low heat cooking or simmering, according to some recipes several hours.

At what temperature should I simmer, in order to avoid burning / overcooking, while still achieving caramelization, reduction and breaking down of the vegetables?

I am talking about the temperature of the sauce, while it simmers.

Comment: have a looksie at this : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19160/what-does-bring-to-a-simmer-mean

Comment: Thx, this is helpful.

Comment: Caramelization should take places when you brown the meat. As for breaking down the vegetables are you meaning the onions? Are you using a pot and a gas stove? Because in that case you adjust the speed of simmering rather than the T.

Comment: I use an electrical stove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what other tasks you have for the day, consider sliding the sauce (and your Dutch Oven) into your oven for 6 hours or so.

> Slow Cooker Setting = Oven Temp
>  Low = 185-200F
>  High =
>   280-300F

I cook my Brunswick Stew this way at 250F (covered 3 hours, uncovered 3 hours). The last 3 hours allows the sauce/broth to thicken through evaporation. The temp allows the stew to "simmer" without repeatedly stirring, worrying over it, and zero scorching! Plus, I'm free to tend to other things.

Related:
[Technique: Slow Cooking with a Slow Cooker](https://www.thekitchn.com/tips-slow-cooking-without-a-sl-109482)
[Slow Cooker vs Dutch Oven: A Conversion Guide](https://blog.williams-sonoma.com/slow-cooker-vs-dutch-oven-a-conversion-guide/)

Comment: One reason this works well is that the heat transfer is very even and gentle because you've got hot air all round rather than a gas flame or electric ring causing local hotspots underneath.