# On what temperature should I leave my sauce to cook?

Tags: sauce, temperature, pizza, cooking-time, tomatoes

I decided to cook a pizza sauce. I know that the longer you leave it on your stove, the better it might taste. I want to leave my sauce on the stove for an hour or so. At what temperature should I keep it?

Comment: There's no specific temperature ... such that you see the occasional bubble, but not so many bubbles that it's spitting tomato sauce everywhere

Comment: usually just under boiling point, or simmering: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19160/what-does-bring-to-a-simmer-mean

Comment: Just put it on the lowest setting.

Comment: Often, pizza sauce is uncooked before topping a pizza.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once it's reached a boil, then drop it to the lowest your burner will go.

With the lid on, the idea is to have just noticeable movement, with as few bubbles as you can get.

Many burners won't go that low; but a tomato sauce should be OK at a low simmer for an hour, so long as you stir it every 10 mins & make sure it doesn't start to stick. If you take the lid off the temperature will drop, but the sauce will reduce quicker.

Alternatively, get one of these simmer rings - a few $£€ on eBay from China. That will let you drop the temperature to lower than bubbling, almost slow-cooker style.
I use one on gas. I don't know what else it's compatible with.

[image]

Comment: I 2nd the recommendation of the simmer ring for a gas burner, they work wonderfully.